# Grpc import google proto Cannot Resolve

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, grpc-c#

I started a new gRPC c# project. But when I try and import a google protobuf I just get an error that it could not be resolved. How do i get this working so i can use Google protobuf library?

[image: Proto Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello i think you use ReSharper extencion, i had a same problem. Try to disable it in resharper [options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhmq6.png)  add *.proto to ignored code.

You can see more information, about this problem, right there https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/language-service-for-protobuf-doesnt-recognise-sta/689208

Comment: Thanks :), That was the fix.